# How to route PropertyChanged event to parent of contentcontrol in order to update GUI?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following parent view, which embeds a contentcontrol as such:

```
<ScrollViewer  Grid.Column="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ContentControl Name="RobotWorkingArea" IsEnabled="{Binding IsRobotAreaEnabled}" Content="{Binding RobotAreaViewModel}" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Since I need my robot working area to be zoomable, I use the scale transform of its grid, which will change when the mouse wheel event is fired:

```
   <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding RenderScaleX}" ScaleY="{Binding RenderScaleY}"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseWheel">
                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="ChangeRenderSize" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PlacementConfiguration.EquipmentPlacementList}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      SelectionMode="Single" Width="{Binding RobotAreaWidth}" Height="{Binding RobotAreaHeight}">
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

This works fine so far (`ChangeRenderSize()` method simply changes the values of `RenderScaleX` and `RenderScaleY` based on the mouse wheel direction) , however the `ScrollViewer` in my parent view doesn't update and change to the new size of the child view. Due to this, if I zoom in I can't reach the whole area and when zoomed out, there is a white background and the `ScrollViewer` stays in its fixed size.

My guess is that the parent doesn't know the current size of the child, since it doesn't see any property changed events. 
The questions now are:

- Is this assumption correct? Or does the issue lie somewhere else?
- If yes, how can I best route the property changed event of `RenderScaleX` and `RenderScaleY` to the parent view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LayoutTransform` property instead of `RenderTransform`:

```
<Grid.LayoutTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding RenderScaleX}" ScaleY="{Binding RenderScaleY}"/>
</Grid.LayoutTransform>
```

`RenderTransform` only applies to the rendering and does not effect the layout which is why the `ScrollViewer` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I use LayoutTransform, does this affect the position of items within the Grid for example, if I use pixel coordinates for the positions of these items? With Rendertransform everything stays in relativ position the the original..

Comment: @RolandDeschain: You are scaling the entire `Grid`, aren't you? But it does effect the layout of the elements.